# If $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle then,

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Given $ab+bc+ca =12$ then what is the least value of $a+b+c$ can we use AM - GM  inequality for solving this problem

Comment: Please detail out exactly what everything means, and what you have tried, and where you get stuck. Also, this reads like a *command*. We prefer to be *asked* to solve things.

Comment: a=2 b=2 c=2 so a+b+c = 6

Comment: I tried solving it by using AM - GM inequality and used triangle inequality

Answer (score 1):

$(a+b+c)^2\geq3(ab+ac+bc)=36$, which gives $a+b+c\geq6$.

The equality occurs for $a=b=c=2$.

We can prove $(a+b+c)^2\geq3(ab+ac+bc)$ by AM-GM:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2+b^2)\geq2\sum_{cyc}ab$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2-ab)\geq0$$ or
$$(a+b+c)^2\geq3(ab+ac+bc)$$